# Should I use common resource bindings across all my shaders in HLSL/D3D12?

Tags: gpu, hlsl, directx12

Will unaccessed bindings consume cache or bandwidth? I want to improve cache usage by splitting the per-path information in my renderer across different resources, but I also want to keep my binding model simple by having every resource I might need declared in a single .hlsli included at the top of each shader file. I'm concerned that the GPU might try to load part of each resource, even if a particular shader doesn't access it - is that reasonable? Should I prefer more descriptor heaps and fewer resources/shader instead?